# Pulseaudio detects wrong sample rate. Forcing pulseaudio a sample rate

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

When using the h2n as USB mic and playback device, it displays 44.1khz as sample rate.

When pulseaudio restarts, it is detected correctly (`pacmd list-sinks`): `sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz`

Now I start playing a video on youtube and while it plays, turn the "Profile" of it in "pavucontrol" -> "Configuration" to "off" and back to "Analog Stereo Duplex". Now pulseaudio tells me: `sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz`

On a fresh system start it's even enough to just open `pavucontrol` to cause the wrong sampling rate.

Which results in a pitched output with a lot of crackling.

---

**Stuff I have tried:**

1.

Make the following changes to `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
default-sample-rate = 44100
avoid-resampling = yes
```

as suggested in another question ([Setting different per-device sampling rates in pulseaudio?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500772/setting-different-per-device-sampling-rates-in-pulseaudio)) and in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

2.

put

```
pcm.device{
    format S16_LE
    rate 41000
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}
pcm.!default{
    type plug
    slave.pcm "device"
}
```

into `~/.asoundrc` and logging out and back in. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141234/227331)

3.

put

```
pcm.!default {
    type rate
    slave {
        pcm "plughw:0,0"
        rate 44100
    }
}
```

into `~/.asoundrc` as suggested here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=400718#p400718 and rebooting.

4.

`pactl list sinks | grep -oP "(?<=device.string = \")(.*)(?=\")" | while read in; do pasuspender -- speaker-test --nloops=1 --channels=2 --test=wav --device=$in; done` as suggested in https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Users/Troubleshooting/ sounds good. Afterwards firefox will resume with crackling noises.

Comment: Possibly the same issue as [Steinberg UR22C Audio Interface Sometimes Low-pitched Playback, Cracks](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256005) but I cannot comment there because I can't register, maybe because I'm not running arch.

Comment: Here is a bug report for this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/980

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Installing cadence and jack2, adding myself to the audio group (`usermod -a -G audio username`), logging back in and setting cadence to use the h2n for input and output it seems to be promising. In pavucontrol I have a "Jack sink" for output and "Jack source" for input and I can select those as default when I need to use it. No crackling yet.

So basically I need to put jack between pulseaudio and alsa to make it work, if I understand the linux audio environment correctly.

---

**Edit**

I have tried to remove pulseaudio completely now. Quite a lot of programs still work, but not all of them. In order to get volume control working I made this: https://github.com/sezanzeb/ALSA-Control. Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293206/227331

---

**Edit 2**

try https://pipewire.org/

Answer (score 5):

Uncomment and set `alternate-sample-rate` to `44100` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` (and remove `~/.asoundrc`).

Comment: Thanks! It seems like this only helped on my laptop (xubuntu 19.04, kernel 5.3.0-51), but not on my computer (manjaro, kernel 5.4.18-1). Both have pulseaudio 13.0. But it's a good start.

Comment: Ony my itx (manjaro, kernel 5.4.13-2) it never even was a problem and always played audio correctly.

Comment: I might reinstall all my stuff on wednesday. I had lots of jack stuff running on the computer and maybe trying to get that nightmare to work messed up everything else

Comment: Reinstalled my computer, added that change and it does not solve the problem unfortunatelly

Comment: One possible reason why this didn't work for me back then could be because `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf` seems to take precedence over `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`